# Where did Samson's Power Bands come from?

Tags: young-samson

New question, about the 60s Hanna-Barbera cartoon series **Young Samson** (or  **Samson & Goliath** as it was later known).

**Basic plot:** a teenager, Samson, and his pet Yorkie Terrier, Goliath, travel around the world, stopping to help avert crisis wherever they are. They do this via use of Samson's "power bracelets", two seemingly bronze bands he wears on his wrist.

When forcefully clashed together, the bands initiate a change, metamorphosing the teenage Samson into a 20-something, super buff, modern-day version of the supposedly biblical Samson, fully endowed with the heroes super-human strength, speed and durability. He also seems to have limited flight and occasional energy beams he can fire from his fingertips.

When things get eve more dire, Samson can clash his bands again, sending out another magical energy wave that changes his 15 lb dog into a 800 lb *lion*, with powers every bit as formidable as his master's. You can see it here:

Thing is...**it's NEVER SHOWN exactly WHERE or HOW Samson got these bands**, to my knowledge.

I know this was a 60s H-B cartoon, so "origin stories" never really occurred; the heroes were just usually "there", with no established "backstory" (this was the case, to my knowledge, with everyone from Space Ghost to Bird Man, Mightor, the Galaxy Trio, and others; the only "pilot" episode I vaguely recall was for *Shazaan* ).

But then, USA used to show many of these episodes out of order.

So... WAS there ever an episode that showed where the bands came from and how Samson got the Power Bands?

I originally thought his dad was an archeologist searching for them, but some criminal mastermind tried to steal them, but before they could get into the wrong hands, they fell into Samson. So now the reason he and Goliath are travelling around as they do would be to find the professor and stop the Crime syndicate. But again, this was H_B in the 60s... it may not have been so in-depth at all.

Just wondering if I had perhaps missed something.

Comment: By the power of Grayskull! Wait, wrong one.

Comment: HA! Funny! I caught that same vibe, though.

Comment: I suspect you've already sensed there is no answer.  Even among the HB cartoons, "Young Samson" was pretty B-List.  He didn't even make the cut in the DC Comics  HB epic mini-series of a couple of years ago, though all the other heroes you list do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there was ever an origin story involving Samson although there was one for Mightor.  He saved an old wizard (is there any other kind?) from a dinosaur (T-Rex?).  The creature was on a giant log that traversed a crevice and Tor (the normal teenage caveman alter ego) used a rod to pry the log and causing the dino to drop into the the ravine saving the wizard.  He rewards Tor with a magical club which when he yells the name, Mightor, transforms into the much larger and muscular hero with a mask and cape to concealed his identity from the tribe and his "girl friend".

My educated H-B sense would say that the Samson origin tale would be similar in nature to that of Mightor.

Comment: I see. So basically, a Dinosaur Days _Captain Marvel/Shazam,_ then? Nice. We can't assume as much without proof, though, but it _does_ offer a possible similar scenario. Either way, this new info is appreciated, partner. Well done.